# Power BI Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'. Incorrect syntax near ')' on stored proc with no parameters (DirectQuery)

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have looked at the articles on stackoverflow about this issue.

I have also reviewed the article for calling stored procedures with parameters at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/execute-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-user-parameter-in-power-bi/.

In my case, I have a stored procedure with no parameters.

I am unclear on how I would apply a fix-up to the M script in Power Query Editor to call a stored procedure with no parameters so that the stored procedure can be recognized and used by Power BI.

Could someone provide guidance for my scenario and steps below?

### Scenario

- I am using a Power BI with DirectQuery.
- I need an ordered list or rows from my database. So I created a stored procedure in my SQL database that simply wraps a SQL `SELECT` statement with an `ORDER BY` clause.
- The stored procedure has no parameters.

### Steps

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, I create and test my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pbiGetFileInfo]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT dbo.CurrentReport.JobId AS CurrentJobId, 
          dbo.jobs.id AS JobId, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Id AS JobInstrumentId, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.InstrumentDescription, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Notes, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Latitude, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Longitude, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Depth,
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport.filename, 
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport.mindate AS FromDate, 
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport.maxdate AS ToDate, 
          DATEDIFF(hour, dbo.jobinstrumentimport.mindate, dbo.jobinstrumentimport.maxdate) AS duration_hours
   FROM   dbo.CurrentReport INNER JOIN
          dbo.jobs ON dbo.CurrentReport.JobId = dbo.jobs.id INNER JOIN
          dbo.JobInstruments ON dbo.jobs.id = dbo.JobInstruments.JobId INNER JOIN
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport ON dbo.JobInstruments.Id = dbo.jobinstrumentimport.jobinstrumentid
   ORDER BY JobInstruments.Id, FromDate

END
GO
```

2. In Power BI, I click the `Transform Data` button to launch the Power Query Editor.
3. Under queries, I right-click the first empty entry in the `Queries` pane and highlight the `New Query` item and click `SQL Server` from the context menu.
4. In the `SQL Server Database` dialog, I enter the `Server` and `Database`.
5. In the `SQL Server Database` dialog, I click the `Advanced Options` link to expand the dialog and show the `SQL statement (optional, requires database)` field.
6. In the `SQL statement (optional, requires database)`, I enter `EXEC [dbo].[pbiGetFileInfo]` and click the `OK` button.
7. A truncated preview of the data returned by the stored procedure is displayed.
8. I click `OK` at the bottom of the preview.
9. A new entry `Query1` appears in the `Queries` pane.
10. I right-click the new `Query1` entry and rename it to `pbiGetFileInfo`.  The M syntax that appears for the query at this point is:

```
= Sql.Database("Server Name", "NWBDatabase", [Query="EXEC [dbo].[pbiGetFileInfo]"])
```

At this point, if I click "Apply" from the Power Query Editor Ribbon, I will get the error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'. Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

11. I click the `Advanced Editor` button on the toolbar. The M script for the pbiGetFileInfo query is:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("Server Name", "NWBDatabase", [Query="EXEC [dbo].[pbiGetFileInfo]"])
in
    Source
```

At this point, I am stuck.

### My questions are:

1. The stored procedure has no parameters.  Do I need to add a `SQLSource` prefix to the M script?  If I do need a `SQLSource`, what would that look like?

```
let
    SQLSource ...
    let
       Source = Sql.Database("Server Name", "NWBDatabase", [Query="EXEC [dbo].[pbiGetFileInfo]"])
   in
       Source
in
   SQLSource
```

2. One thought is to create a view in SQL that calls the stored procedure.  I have tried this and found that the view returns the same warning in Power BI as you would see if you tried to create a View with an ORDER BY in SQL. Calling views from Power BI is problematic at best.
3. Is there any way to write a stored procedure in SQL that minimizes the workarounds required to use them from Power BI?

### Updates

- I cannot call a stored procedure from Power BI under DirectQuery.  It returns the same error `Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC' message. I need to see the DAX that is created to find the source of this error.
- If I try the raw SQL Select from the stored procedure that I am trying to call, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft SQL: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views.
```

Note: this is using straight SQL SELECT.  The word VIEW is does not exist in the SQL SYNTAX at all.

- A SQL Select that calls a VIEW *only* works if the calling outer SELECT contains a TOP (100) PERCENT clause. For example:

My view named `[pbiGetFileInfo]` contains the following SELECT statement:

```
    SELECT dbo.CurrentReport.JobId AS CurrentJobId, 
          dbo.jobs.id AS JobId, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Id AS JobInstrumentId, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.InstrumentDescription, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Notes, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Latitude, 
          dbo.JobInstruments.Longitude, 
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport.filename, 
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport.mindate AS FromDate, 
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport.maxdate AS ToDate, 
          DATEDIFF(hour, dbo.jobinstrumentimport.mindate, dbo.jobinstrumentimport.maxdate) AS duration_hours
   FROM   dbo.CurrentReport INNER JOIN
          dbo.jobs ON dbo.CurrentReport.JobId = dbo.jobs.id INNER JOIN
          dbo.JobInstruments ON dbo.jobs.id = dbo.JobInstruments.JobId INNER JOIN
          dbo.jobinstrumentimport ON dbo.JobInstruments.Id = dbo.jobinstrumentimport.jobinstrumentid
```

The view itself does not contain an `ORDER BY` clause.

When I try to call this from a SQL SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[pbiGetFileInfo] ORDER BY Id,FromDate
```

I get the error:

```
Microsoft SQL: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views...
```

It works if I revise the SELECT to:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT * FROM [dbo].[pbiGetFileInfo] ORDER BY Id,FromDate
```

But, I am not sure it this will work correctly in Power BI DirectQuery.

- My first thought is that Power BI seems to treat everything as a SQL VIEW. So all data sources are subject to the limitations of views.  None of the advantages of sorting on a SQL Server are actually available in Power BI under DirectQuery.  If you have to set the sort order in Power BI, there may be significant performance penalties.
- I am experimenting with Table-Valued Functions (but have no faith that this will work in Power BI).

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Why don't you just change your stored procedure to a view? It has no parameters and is just a single SELECT statement. Whatever you are pointing and clicking at is obviously trying to wrap your stored procedure call with `SELECT * FROM ([query=...)x;` and you're going to have a real hard time forcing that to call a procedure using e.g. `OPENQUERY`. Maybe check your tooling's documentation to see if they support stored procedures (they must) or, like I started with, just make your procedure a view. (Also, a view has a similar issue "calling" a stored procedure - doesn't really work like that.)

Comment: Hi Aaron, - I need an ordered set of rows.  I can try this but Views throw errors if the query that you are referencing contains an ORDER BY.  I have not been able to successfully create a view that calls a SQL SELECT or STORED PROC that contains a ORDER BY.  The ORDER BY is not a part of the view wrapping the call.  I still get the error.

Comment: That's because you put the `ORDER BY` in the statement that uses the `VIEW`, @DougKimzey . `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourView YV ORDER BY YV.YourColumn;` `VIEW`s are intentionally unordered.

Comment: I get that.  My View does not contain an ORDER BY.  The ORDER BY is on the SQL SELECT inside the SP.  I still get the error.